# JQueryUI modal focus on close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When using the JQueryUI modal dialog, the close button is automatically focused leading the title exposed through the jquery tooltip. I want nothing in the modal to be focused. I have tried to add a click trigger on the title of the modal window, but it seems that it had no effect.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try triggering the blur event on the close button after the modal shows up.

Ex:

```
$('close-button-selector-here').blur();
```

Comment: In a couple of seconds, yes. There is a time limit :) 
- done

Comment: Yea, when I first commented there was an alert saying that I could accept it in two minutes :)