# jQuery modal dialog focus automatically goes to "Close" button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have jQuery tooltips bound to the $(document)

I am opening a modal jQuery dialog and **loading content via ajax, then resizing and centering the dialog once loaded** but Im having the following problem:-

When I open the modal dialog, focus jumps straight to the "Close" (X) button in the top right and the tooltip "Close" pops up and then because the window is being resized once content is loaded, the tooltip never disappears and ends up floating in the middle of the dialog.

I have seen [this post with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16315284/175893), and the solution is fine, I just cant seem to find an event to host the `$('close-button-selector-here').blur();` method call.

Comment: can you post a fiddle ? and have you tried putting the blur in open event ? http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open

Comment: I have tried putting it in the open event, but it appears (if you put an `alert` there) that the dialog has in fact not yet rendered at that stage and hence, not yet displayed the tooltip. BTW - I havent used Fiddle before and I cant even get http://jsfiddle.net/zFtjY/1/ to work!!?